# Why do I get the error "Array indices must be positive integers or logical values" in MATLAB

Tags: function, matlab, math

I need to write the [function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ECrd.png) among others in MATLAB, but I keep getting "Array indices must be positive integers or logical values." error and an error for both functions f(x) and u(x) saying "Error in f(x(j)) = ..." or "Error in u(x(j)) = ....." Why is that?

This is the code relating to that

```
for j=1:n
    x(j)=-1+j*h;          
    f(x(j)) = (pi.^2).*(exp(cos(pi.*x(j)))).*(cos(pi.*x(j))-(sin(pi.*x(j))).^2);
    u(x(j))= -f(x(j));
end
```

Answer (score 1):

The error coming from the value of **h** must be **integer** for example:

if  h = 1;   f(1), u(1) **no error**

if  h = 1.3; f(1.3), u(1.3)  **error**

The is no reserved place in array **f(1.3)** by 1.3;

Fix h value by an **integer** to solve the error.

```
n = 99; 
h = 2; 
x = ones(n,1); 
f = ones(n,1); 
u = ones(n,1);

for j=1:n
    x(j)    = -1+j*h;   
    f(x(j)) = (pi.^2).*(exp(cos(pi.*x(j)))).*(cos(pi.*x(j))-(sin(pi.*x(j))).^2);
    u(x(j)) = -f(x(j));
end
```

Comment: I have ````   n=99;           
  h= 2;       
  x=ones(n,1);      
  f=ones(n,1);      
  u=ones(n,1); ```` but it still gives the error

Comment: h must not be = 0 or 1 coz the value of x(j) = 0, matlab not allowed f(0), it start from 1.

Comment: But I don't have h = 0 or h=1. I thought maybe there is a mistake in my function? Maybe I misplaced a .^ or .* somewhere ?

Comment: Oh ok, thank you so much!!

Comment: I'm happy to help.